# Calculate tfidf for query result in solr

Tags: python-3.x, solr

I am trying to calculate tfidf using python, the document am working on is a csv file generated from solr, it has already been indexed. is there a way i can access the indexes because it is seeing the columns as string instead of a string and value

[csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZTCV.png)[code to see length of sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkiDt.png)

[result showing 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXiAX.png)

[trying to check the no of columns, it shows they are not separated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YupGd.png)

How can I make use of the number for my calculation please

Comment: Please put your code into the question rather than attaching an image. It makes it much easier for other people to help you and not everyone can access those links.

Comment: Also be aware that Solr isn't using a pure TF/IDF calculation, so your scores won't be comparable if you're attempting to do that

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I already got a way out of it.